# How to enable TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher with Apache 2.4 and mod_ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

So I've been bashing my head with this problem for the last few hours.

The problem is, that I have an iOS app which loads in some web content.
The attempts to do its job just fine but chokes with the error "An SSL Error has occured and a secure connection to the server cannot be made".

I ran the URL through SSLLabs and saw that I had the following error listed under Handshake Simulation:

`Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9    "Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure"`

Without knowing much about it, it seems to be related to not being able to provide a cipher to the app's WebView which can guarantee *Forward Secrecy*.

The list of acceptable ciphers for `Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9` is listed [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Apple%20ATS&version=9&platform=iOS%209).

I matched that list to the output of `openssl ciphers` which I've provided [here](http://pastebin.com/6zrJcfes)

First of all, the ciphers from the openssl list and the ciphers from SSLLabs looks to be in two different formats/naming conventions. But besides that, it looks like I don't support any of the `ECDHE_ECDSA[...]` unless I'm just reading it wrong.

In lack of anything better to do I've just been messing around with it and my host's SSL configuration now has these lines in them:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-
SHA384:HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
```

That seems to do absolutely nothing.

It stops making any sense at all for me when I look at the TLSv1.2 ciphers SSLLabs reports being available. I've put that list [her](http://pastebin.com/gYPZZuBu). In my view, that doesn't correspond at all to what I've defined in `SSLCipherSuite` - but comparing that list with the list of supported ciphers for ATS it seems quite clear why it's complaining.

I admit, I'm a bit over my head here - I'd like to understand what's going on but I honestly don't know where to start.

1. Do I have the right ciphers installed?
2. If not, where do I get them (I'm currently on openssl 1.0.2k and Apache 2.4.25)
3. If I do have the right ciphers available how does the openssl list correspond to the list from SSLLabs?
4. How do I enable the right ciphers on the server?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If this is really the full list of ciphers detected by SSLLabs then you probably have another SSLCipherSuite definition somewhere in the apache config. Note that it is not possible to have different SSLCipherSuite for different VirtualHost so please check all configuration files.

Comment: Your cipher names are wrong as you've observed (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html has both formats listed). I'm not sure why you wouldn't have any ECDHE ciphers but give this a try: https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.4.18&openssl=1.0.2k&hsts=no&profile=intermediate

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm certain that there isn't another config. Well, at least as certain as I can be. I'm testing on a setup with only a single VirtualHost.

Comment: Thank you @AnandBhat, didn't find that list on my own. I'll give it a look.

Comment: @ChristianA.Rasmussen: This definition can also be outside of VirtualHost. Is there only a single configuration file for apache? Could it be that there is some reverse proxy or load balancer in front of your site which terminates the SSL connection with its own ciphers?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've gone through (what I believe is) all configuration files. What I'm playing with is the one :)

I can also see SSLLabs react to my changes... just now the way I want it to.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich nope. No proxy or load balancer. This server is at the edge. I tried to configure it as guided by Mozilla with a modern configuration. It includes this cipher as the first one: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 which I assume should correspond to ATS' requirement of TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. Still doesn't pop up right in SSLLabs.

Thank you for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianA.Rasmussen: I just had a look at the output of `openssl ciphers` you've posted and I don't see any ECC support there, i.e. no ECDHE and ECDSA ciphers. I would suggest that you are running on a system where openssl was compiled without ECC support which explains why you cannot get these ciphers in Apache too. What kind of OS (and version) is this?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You were absolutely right. I'm on Gentoo and they've introduced a USE flag, bindist, which deactives EC crypto from openssl and openssh. That was it.

Side question - it still doesn't seem to work. Can a certificate be made su that it doesn't support EC at all since I made the CSR from when openssl didn't have EC ciphers?

Comment: @ChristianA.Rasmussen: all certificates can be use together with ECDHE key exchange. But, did you only rebuild openssl or also apache so that it uses the rebuild libssl?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - sigh. You are the smarter one of us once again... No, I only rebuilt openssl and openssh (for some reason). Thank you for getting my mind back on track. That's most likely it.

Comment: What is the server name or URL? If you suspect the problem is the cipher suites (and inclusion of RSA key exchange; or lack of ephemeral Diffie-Hellman), then use the `SSLCipherSuite` string  `"HIGH:!kRSA:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. All your comments were a point in the right direction.
However, I found the real culprit(s) to be a USE flag on `dev-libs/openssh` and `net-misc/openssl`. Due to licensing issues the ciphers I was looking for were not included due to the lack of the `bindist` flag being enabled by default.

I added both to my `/etc/portage/packages.use` with `bindist` disabled. Like this:

```
dev-libs/openssl -bindist
net-misc/openssh -bindist
```

And then I recompiled both. After rebuilding both packages and everything which depended on them, all my ECDHE_ECDSA[...] ciphers were readily available.